# jQuery - Error in event handler for 'undefined': TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: jquery, django, google-chrome

I have my own templates with this code in head:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}emotions.js"></script>
```

But in Chrome code spectrator i always have:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
```

emotions.js:

```
$(function(){
        $('.emotion').click(function(){
                  var id = $(this).parent().attr('id')
                  $.post("something/vote/", { emotion: "emotion", id: "id" } )
        $('.vote_value').text('You give your vote')});
});
```

Any sugegestions of what could be wrong?

Comment: 10:1 the failure is located in `emotions.js`

Comment: what would display **{{MEDIA_URL}}**..?

Comment: {{MEDIA_URL}} give value which is url path to file emotions.js

Comment: have you tried with echo that {{MEDIA_URL}}..? may be its need only **{MEDIA_URL}**..

Comment: no, for sure I need {{MEDIA_URL}} and for sure it is good writen. It is django feature, context variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost guarantee that if you log `$('.vote_value')`, you'll get undefined. Make sure you have an element with that class present in the dom.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error if you ask for the `html()` of a `<title>` element. For example:

```
var title = $('title');
var t = title.html();
//-> Error in event handler for 'undefined': TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
var t = title[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
//-> "Welcome to My Page!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've that error too. I've just turned off an "adBlock" extension. Than I restarted my server and the error disappered.